# Exporting CSV response laravel does not download file but show the all value in response

Tags: laravel

public function jobCandidateBreakdown($job_export_csv_id){
$fileName = 'Healthdaq - Admin Candidate Breakdown.csv';
$applied_jobs= AppliedJob::where('job_id',$job_export_csv_id)->with('job')->get();
$headers = array(
"Content-type"        => "text/csv",
"Content-Disposition" => "attachment; filename=$fileName",
"Pragma"              => "no-cache",
"Cache-Control"       => "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0",
"Expires"             => "0"
);

```
    $columns = array('Company Name','Candidate', 'Email','MOBILE','Source','Job','Job type', 'Current Status', 'Department', 'Headline', 'Date Added','Stage','Question','Answer');
    $callback = function() use($applied_jobs, $columns) {
        $file = fopen('php://output', 'w');
        fputcsv($file, $columns);

        foreach ($applied_jobs as $applied_job) {
            if($applied_job->candidate)
                {

               $row['Company_name']  = $applied_job->job->companies->company_name;
                $row['Candidate']  = $applied_job->candidate->user_name;
                $row['Email']  = $applied_job->candidate->users->email;
                $row['phone_number']  = $applied_job->jobApplicantionFormData() ? $applied_job->jobApplicantionFormData()->phone_number : '';
                $row['Source']  = $applied_job->source;
                $row['Job']  = $applied_job->job->job_title;
                $row['Job_type']  =  $applied_job->job->getType() ;
                $row['Current_Status']  = $applied_job->job->status;
                $row['Department']  = $applied_job->job->departments->name;
                $row['Headline']  = $applied_job->jobApplicantionFormData() ? $applied_job->jobApplicantionFormData()->heading : '';
                $row['Date_Added']  = $applied_job->created_at->format('d/m/y h:s');
                $row['Stage']  = $applied_job->workflow_stage;
                $array = [
                    $row['Company_name'],
                    $row['Candidate'],
                    $row['Email'],
                    $row['phone_number'],
                    $row['Source'] ,
                    $row['Job'],
                    $row['Job_type'],
                    $row['Current_Status'],
                    $row['Department'] ,
                    $row['Headline'] ,
                    $row['Date_Added'],
                    $row['Stage'],
                ];
                   if($applied_job->jobApplicantionFormData()){
                foreach($applied_job->jobApplicantionFormData()->jobApplicationCustomAnswers as $value){
                    $row['question']  = $value ? $value->question : '';
                    $row['answer']  = $value ? $value->answer : '';
                    array_push($array,$row['question'],$row['answer']);
                }

            }
                fputcsv($file, $array);
    }


        }

        fclose($file);
    };
    // dd("hello");
    Auth::user()->createLog('Exported report (Candidate Breakdown Report)');
    return response()->stream($callback, 200, $headers);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `streamDownload` method insted of `stream` method.

Comment: not working streamDownload